# where i can find The Agora HTTP basic authorization token?

Tags: video-streaming, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

How to find  **Agora** HTTP basic authorization token from my agora account? I'm trying to build a *webapp*.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure communication security, when users join an RTC channel or you start recording on the server, Agora needs to check their authentication information and tokens are one of the mechanisms you can use to ensure this.

Token is a dynamic key generated by App ID, App Certificate, user ID, channel name, token expiration timestamp, and other information. For scenarios requiring high-security, such as the production environment, Agora recommends using a token for authentication.

You can find the Auth Token in the Project info panel of the [Dashboard Console](https://console.agora.io) page. You can click view icon to display the token.

**Documentation Link:** https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Platform/token#generate-a-token

**Sample Apps:**

1. Node.js: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/TokenServer-nodejs
2. Go Lang: https://github.com/digitallysavvy/agora-token-service

**Dynamic Key Official Repo:** https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/tree/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.